# Adding labels to explorations data in GA4?

Tags: label, report, visualization, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

Is it possible to add an arbitrary label to a GA4 exploration?

For example I am tracking outbound link clicks for phone numbers. I would like to add a short description to each number.

I was thinking something like if Link URL equals 'tel: xx xxxx xxx' a label would say 'city office'. Any ideas on this?

[image: GA4 exploration view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... You have GTM tag added to your question. This implies that you're ok having a GTM solution.

Well, in GTM, find the tag that fires on the phone clicks, add a custom event property to the tag that would contain the description of the numbers, make a custom JS (CJS) or a look up table (LUT) or better a regex LUT, and map your numbers to descriptions.

Then go to GA and register that event property as a custom dimension. Done.

You could also override the link url dimension in GTM with a CJS var that would generate descriptions in the same dimension, but it's not a good idea to override default dimensions unless you're confident about what you're doing.

GA4 has capabs to modify event properties, but it's extremely basic and won't be able to change properties based on their values. Also, it's a bad idea to have data modification logic in GA. It's best to contain all data modification logic in one place whenever you can help it.

Comment: you're right i was using GTM. 
I used a LUT variable to map the Click URL value to the definition i wanted. Did the whole custom Tag and Trigger that sent the values to GA4, created a custom definition in GA4 and used that in my exploration. 

Mind blown! Thanks BNazaruk

Comment: Great job. Normally people have more questions along this journey, but it's good it was swift for you.